# Absent due to sickness make up by working late hours

Tags: employees, after-hours

I was recently absent a day from work due to the flu.I usually stay back late hours and work. So I missed 8 hours that day I was absent but working two hours extra over regular work hours would see me make up those lost hours in 4 days. Would that count as me making up the hours for that day based on the extra hours I work?

Comment: Technically, yes. In reality, it depends on your status and the company policy. If the implicit question is, "Do i need to use one day of my holiday", the answer is company-specific.

Comment: Not sure where you are from, but what is the point of sick *leave*, if you have to work extra hours to "make up" for it?

Comment: Am a contract person working within the company on improving some software they use, Am not sure if it works the same as regular staff

Comment: What does your contract say about sick leave? I hope you did not sign the contract without reading it.

Comment: I read it.  Just didn't have anything about sick leave. Seems to me am just being treated as a supplier

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on who you ask, your manager or your HR representative.

( Speaking US here )

Most managers of salaried employees would be able to make that work **if they wanted to**, unless a specific HR policy prohibits this.

If your an hourly employee most likely that won't work and you will have to take a PTO day.

In short I would start a conversation with your manager to see if this arrangement is agreeable to them.

Comment: That's very interesting because I know a lot of places that won't ;-)

Answer (score 6):

> Would that count as me making up the hours for that day based on the
>   extra hours I work?

The only way to know what "counts" and what doesn't is to ask.

Ask your manager, and ask whoever it is that manages your time within the company. You will be asking permission here - unless there's something in your contract, you aren't automatically permitted to "make up hours" this way.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you feel the need to do this when you are sick you take sick leave (or the equivalent for your country)

Just take your sick leave and work normally on your return.

I hope you are paid OT for the extra 2 hours you seem to be working.

Comment: You're assuming that the OP has sick leave to take.

Comment: The OP implied he was an employee - though it seems they are a contactor which might change things

Comment: Not everybody even gets sick leave from their employer. The majority of people in the UK (as an example) only get statutory sick pay, which only kicks in when you've been absent for four days - and you don't get your full salary, it's only £88.45/week for up to 28 weeks.

Comment: @HerrPink don't think this applies for a single day, ssp  is when of your of for an extended period

Comment: Many US workers get no sick leave at all.

Comment: @Neuromancer: Yep, that's what I said in my comment :) My point was that most people in the UK don't get sick leave at all, so it's not uncommon for people in the UK to 'make up' missed hours by working OT so that they don't lose out on earnings because they were sick.